# Virtual Host Setup Redirecting Request to Local IP address

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, apache2, moodle

I want to make an application running on apache2 (ubuntu) available over the internet. So i decided to setup virtual host after purchasing a SSL certificate. Everything works fine on my Local network.

When I visit 172.16.2.28/moodle (on local network), Everything works fine.

When I also visit example.com, I am served the default index.php from (/var/www/html)

But when I visit example.com/moodle over public internet, the browser redirects to 172.16.2.28/moodle (with error 404)

What am I doing wrong.

-

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html



        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  
</VirtualHost>
```

- 

**default-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin sa@xxx.com
                ServerName lms.xxx.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html 

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                
                SSLEngine on

                
                SSLCertificateFile      /home/vlms/sslcert/cert.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/vlms/sslcert/cert.key

                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>
                <Directory /var/www/html/>

                     Options +FollowSymlinks

                     AllowOverride All

                     Require all granted

                 </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

- 

**moodle/config.php** (could the problem be from here?)

```
<?php  // Moodle configuration file

unset($CFG);
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();

$CFG->dbtype    = 'mariadb';
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = '172.16.0.30';
$CFG->dbname    = 'xxx';
$CFG->dbuser    = 'xxx';
$CFG->dbpass    = 'xxx';
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';
$CFG->dboptions = array (
  'dbpersist' => 0,
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbsocket' => '',
  'dbcollation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
);

$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://172.16.0.30/moodle';
$CFG->dataroot  = '/var/www/moodledata';
$CFG->admin     = 'xxx';

$CFG->directorypermissions = 0777;

require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/setup.php');

// There is no php closing tag in this file,
// it is intentional because it prevents trailing whitespace problems!
```

Comment: There are no redirects there. It sounds like your redirect is coming from Moodle.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for your response, I edited the post. I added the moodle/config.php file, please see if you can figure out where i went wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moodle redirects you exactly how you configured it:

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://172.16.0.30/moodle';
```

Change that line to the proper URL:

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'https://example.com/moodle';
```

Comment: Thanks @GeraldSchneider . It works now. But I still get some error in console.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://lms.xxx.com/moodle/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://172.16.0.30/moodle/?redirect=0'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Any Idea?

Comment: Check the developer tools of your browser which images are affected, find out where their URLs come frome and correct them.